# Using `navigator.credentials.get()` in cross-origin iframe gives error "'publickey-credentials-get' feature is not enabled in this document"

Tags: iframe, response-headers, webauthn, fido, http-permissions-policy

Getting the error while logging into an iframe through webauthn.

> The 'publickey-credentials-get' feature is not enabled in this
> document. Permissions Policy may be used to delegate Web
> Authentication capabilities to cross-origin child frames.

Here is the link to the example https://jsfiddle.net/14kj25nr/. I have registered a user "test_account" directly through webauthn.io and then tried to login into it through jsfiddle. It says to use `publickey-credentials-get`, but I couldn't find a way to use it to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Update 1:

I have added the allow attribute for the iframe `allow="publickey-credentials-get"`. It still gives me the same error. The example in the fiddle is updated.

Update 2:

From IAmKale's suggestion. I made the following changes but still got the same error.
Updated the allow attribute of iframe `allow="publickey-credentials-get *"`.

I use the `Requestly` chrome extension to add the `Permissions-Policy` header in the RP's response. It can be seen in the below screenshot that I was able to successfully add the header in the response. But still getting the same error. Could it be some `jsfiddle` specific issue? Or is there anything I am doing wrong? I am using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110.
[image]

Update 3:

When I use the iframe in localhost instead of jsfiddle, I am getting webauthn chrom pop-up. But the log-in is still unsuccessful, the server returns `POST https://webauthn.io/assertion 400`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on Tim's answer, the site embedding the RP will need to add the following `allow` attribute:

```
<iframe src="..." allow="publickey-credentials-get *" />
```

The spec is a little ambiguous about this, but digging into [Permissions Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions-policy-1/) a bit I believe the RP also needs to set the following HTTP header in the response to the URL specified in the iframe's `src`:

```
Permissions-Policy: publickey-credentials-get=*
```

If you want more granular control you can whitelist specific URLs that are allowed to embed the RP's site:

```
# Only specific sites
Permissions-Policy: publickey-credentials-get=("https://example.com")
```

With `https://example.com` being the URL of the page that's embedding the RP's site in the `<iframe>`

Once both pieces are in place I think you'll be able to trigger `navigator.credentials.get()` in the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was helpful. I am still getting the same error. I updated the questions after trying your suggestions. Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Made some progress. Now It's the server that gives 400 error. I can log in fine if I directly go to `webauthn.io`

Comment: @tarun14110 Have you been able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

> The Web Authentication API is disabled by default in cross-origin iframes. To override this default policy and indicate that a cross-origin iframe is allowed to invoke the Web Authentication API's [[DiscoverFromExternalSource]](origin, options, sameOriginWithAncestors) method, specify the allow attribute on the iframe element and include the publickey-credentials-get feature-identifier token in the allow attribute’s value.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-iframe-guidance

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the allow attributed to the iframe. Still getting the same error. If you know, can you please point me to thecorrect way to use it?